# A method driver.find_element_xxx() gets frozen for 2 minutes

Tags: python, selenium

On a website at some step when I'm calling:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fdsfds")
```

it gets completely frozen and nothing happens at all for the next 2 minutes or so.

The element I'm trying to find is visible and enabled for sure. I can click on it in a browser. 
Even if it wasn't, why would the code get frozen?

Any pointers? Is it some kind of protection from bots?

Comment: Hi, are you having a wait command before this statement?

Comment: You should wait for a while before the execution of this statement. Give it some seconds of wait and then see.

Comment: What driver are you using? Is it reproducible in both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @alecxe, firefox. I haven't tried on chrome yet. It seems any "find_element_by" gets frozen this way. After 2 minutes everything works fine. And on some pages on that website it works fine initially.

Comment: @AlanCoromano what I suspect is that it might be specific to specific firefox and selenium versions. Please try with Chrome and try upgrading `selenium` if not on the latest version: `pip install --upgrade selenium`.

Comment: @alecxe, no. why don't you think it's a protection again scrapers and bots?

Comment: @AlanCoromano could u please post the complete code so that I can try reproducing it too and check the theories I have? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, it's just "find_element_by_xx".

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined `driver.implicitly_wait(120)`, that means the driver is waiting up to two minutes to the element to show, and the `driver` couldn't find your element.

Better solution will be to use explicit wait

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fdsfds"))
```

The driver will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be presence in the DOM.